# Dynamic pivot data with multiple datatypes

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have a trick problem with a pivot table to make:

I have a table which looks like:

```
id  table   object  name     type   nvarchar    date    int     bit  
1   1       2       name     1      tables      NULL    NULL    NULL  
2   1       2       name     1      columns     NULL    NULL    NULL  
3   1       2       name     1      datatypes   NULL    NULL    NULL  
4   1       2       name     1      _users      NULL    NULL    NULL  
1   1       3       active   3      NULL        NULL    NULL    1  
2   1       3       active   3      NULL        NULL    NULL    1  
3   1       3       active   3      NULL        NULL    NULL    1  
4   1       3       active   3      NULL        NULL    NULL    1
```

the output should look like:

```
id   name       active   
1    tables     1  
2    columns    1  
3    datatypes  1  
4    _users     1
```

Based upon the "type" I should put the correct data from the column in it, these columns are formated in nvarchar, bit, datetime, int, ect.

The "id" is the row id, the "name, active" comes from the name column and the values from nvarchar, date, int and bit columns.

UPDATE: the columns like nvarchar, date, int and bit (and most other SQL formats) are actually contain this type of data. The column "type" gives which column contains the data to being used, so if "type" is "1", than I want to use the "nvarchar" if "type" is "3" than I want to use the "bit" which contains really a bit and not a nvarchar. In the Pivot I want to have the bit under "active" column, if I have in the example a 3th column (name) for example "activation_date" I want to see a third column with the value (type = 2) from the date column.

I am lost in this, please help

Comment: SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's only one not null column for each row:

```
with cte as (
    select
        id,
        name,
        coalesce(
            [nvarchar],
            convert(nvarchar(max), [date], 120),
            cast([int] as nvarchar(max)),
            cast([bit] as nvarchar(max))
        ) as value
    from Table1 as t
)
select
    id,
    max(case when [name] = 'name' then value end) as [name],
    max(case when [name] = 'active' then value end) as [active]
from cte
group by id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d40c1/6)</kbd>**

But I must warn you, this types of database schema is not best way to use SQL.

If you want to do this dynamically without hardcoding columns:

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt =
   isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') +
   'max(case when [name] = ''' + name + ''' then value end) as ' + quotename([name])
from (select distinct [name] from Table1) as t

select @stmt = '
with cte as (
    select
        id,
        name,
        coalesce(
            [nvarchar],
            convert(nvarchar(max), [date], 120),
            cast([int] as nvarchar(max)),
            cast([bit] as nvarchar(max))
        ) as value
    from Table1 as t
)
select
    id, ' + @stmt + '
from cte
group by id
'

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d40c1/8)</kbd>**

If you have some `Mapping` table like this:

```
name       value
--------------------
name       nvarchar
active     bit
```

you can use this query:

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt =
   isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') +
   'max(case when [name] = ''' + name + ''' then [' + value + '] end) as ' + quotename([name])
from Mapping

select @stmt = '
select
    id, ' + @stmt + '
from Table1
group by id
'

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc77e/2)</kbd>**

Comment: Yes, I would like to avoid anything what look like MAX, SUM, COUNT as these tables will be quite big, anyway thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Also image type is not supported by PIVOT?

Comment: I can't use static names the column names are coming from the table (ed. name and active)

Comment: you have to use aggregate fo PIVOT anyway. You have to convert your data into varchar because you want to show it in one column. You can use xml trick but it performs not so good

Comment: No dont want to show it in on column just the right data in the right column, so for example a nvarchar in nvarchar, bit in a bit. basicly every column which I need need to add the right formatted column with corresponding data as in the example

Comment: No dont want to show it in on column just the right data in the right column, so for example a nvarchar in nvarchar, bit in a bit. basicly every column which I need need to add the right formatted column with corresponding data as in the example. About the aggregate yes you right, however on the id column as there is a index on this one, not a big fan of using this on text, certainly not on large datasets with heavy load

Comment: you have to have some mapping like column, type somewhere if you don't want to convert your data to varchar

Comment: yes I have different columns with these datatypes so when I want to write away I put it in these columns and same story when I want to get it, I will try ur advise today and keep you posted on this

Comment: Than this should be the table....     CREATE TABLE Table1
 ([id] int, [table] int, [object] int, [name] varchar(6), [type] int, [nvarchar] varchar(9), [date] datetime, [int] int, [bit] bit)
;